# In SSRS Report table is there a way to have two sets of repeating groups?

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to add two child groups to a SSRS Report table where both repeat all row details? The In this report I get all the check in times but only one checkout time.  I'm hoping to have a list of both organized by Supplier ID.

[image: My SSRS Group Layout, only one subgroup repeats]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this but not using the Editor. I edited the rdl as a text file and added the following inside  below the TablixMember for Group Name=SupplierID #2.

```
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <Group Name="Details4" />
                      <TablixMembers>
                        <TablixMember />
                      </TablixMembers>
                    </TablixMember>
                    <TablixMember>
                      <KeepWithGroup>Before</KeepWithGroup>
                    </TablixMember>
                  </TablixMembers>
                </TablixMember>
```

This gave me the following groupings:

[image: Groupings with 2 sets of details]